# Como fazer a imagem ficar 100% na tela?

Tags: html, css, css3, imagem, bootstrap

Eu tenho um site em desenvolvimento.

Aí eu quero que ele fique na tela toda, é pra ser um site responsivo, eu tô usando o bootstrap...
Ele só fica em tela cheia se eu der zoom de 150%: Exemplo: https://prnt.sc/fe1fig

Se eu deixar normal ele fica assim: Exemplo: https://prnt.sc/fe1fn6
Minha tela é Full HD.

A imagem tem tamanho de 1400 x 767.

O link do meu código é esse: https://codepen.io/sandsoncosta/pen/XRLvvW

Ele não tá todo formatadinho,

mas aqui tá o link do arquivo completo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28SaVWuwZ5kSlZURWlWRlljdjg/view?usp=sharing

O meu arquivo em html e css.

Aí como que eu faço pra deixar ele na tela toda?

Espero que você me ajudem, obrigado.

PS.: Eu tô estudando responsividade do site, iniciando do início, pra rodar em desktop e mobile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah sim entendi, está usando **background**.

Tente isso

```css
#banner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 728px;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url(../img/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size 100% 100%;
}
```

Assim a imagem de fundo ocupará os 100% do elemento o qual faz parte. Vi lá no código que **section** está com **width** de 100%, então isso deve resolver seu problema

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar

```
background-size: cover;
```

para o elemento em questão!

Comment: uuuuhuhuhuhuhu! Deu certo! Vlw irmão!

Comment: Que legal!
Bom desenvolvimento :)

Comment: Podes explicar porque esta solução resolve a pergunta? Assim outros podem perceber o porquê.

Comment: Olá, Sergio! Acredito que há ainda outros atributos que resolveriam a situação, como "auto" e "contain". O atributo "cover" faz com que o tamanho da imagem que cobre o background seja a maior possível para a área em questão

Answer (score 0):

Para que uma imagem fique em tela cheia você deve usar as propriedades CSS.
Tente usar:

```css
img {
  display :block;
  width : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{
  display :block;
  width : 100%;
}
```

Não deu certo. Eu não consigo resolver esse problema. Tem a ver com o tamanho da imagem? Minha tela é 1920... Tô quebrando a cabeça!

Answer (score 0):

Não tem a ver com o tamanho da imagem não, deveria preencher a tela mesmo que perdesse qualidade. Veja esse exemplo :

https://codepen.io/EdySilva/pen/PmMqgV

O bootstrap pode estar influenciando, tente usar :

```css
img{
  display:block !important;
  width:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Ah, cara! Eu entendi! Nesse caso aí é o seguinte. Minha imagem não ta na tag img, ela tá dentro de uma section, dentro de uma div com id. A imagem é puxada no css, tá no código que eu coloquei no codepen: https://codepen.io/sandsoncosta/pen/XRLvvW... Essa section é pra fazer um slide entre duas imagens. Na img sozinha ela vai normalmente, Entendeu agora?

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte.

```css
#banner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 728px;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url(../img/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size :100% 100%;
}
```

Isso deixará a imagem ocupando 100% de largura e de altura da section, ou seja terá o mesmo tamanho da section. Bastando assim fazer com que a section ocupe a tela.